# Vector spaces $V=-V$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a question about vector spaces:

Since vector spaces have additive inverses, does that mean that $-V=V$?

Comment: What is $V$ in your question?

Comment: $V$ is the set of all vectors in a vector space @5xum

Answer (score 1):

> Since vector spaces have additive inverses, does that mean that $-V=V$?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed. 
Since one of the axioms of the vector space is that if $V$ is a vector space and $v \in V$, then $kv \in V$ for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$, in particular for $k=-1$. Thus, $-V \subseteq V$. Similar argument can yield $V \subseteq -V$, which means $V=-V$

Answer (score 1):

If by $-V$ you mean $-V=\{-v, v\in V\}$, then the answer is almost obviously *yes*.

- If $v\in V$, then $v=-(-v)$ and since $-v\in V$, then $v\in -V$
- If $v\in -V$, then $v=-w$ for some $w\in V$, meaning $v\in V$.